# How do I change the Editor Eclipse colors?

Tags: eclipse, user-preferences

This is in the theme itself.  When I load up the theme I get these colors by default.

[image]

- I'll go clockwise starting on the left.  The collapse/expand arrow is black. and can't see it.
- The highlighted Editors word is black and tough to read
- The links in after the word See are very hard to read
- The black fonts I'd like to see in white
- The radio buttons below the words "When all editors..." is very hard to read

I've tried messing with this all morning and simply can't find a way to change these colors.  I am using the Moonrise Default (current) Theme and have tried to work with this however I can't seem to adjust these colors.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by: "These are NOT colors highlighted when I'm coding"  ?

Comment: When I change to the Moonrise Default (current) Theme I get these colors and I'm unsure of how to change them.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear about what I meant.